# Using a custom APN for a connection

Tags: android, apn

I am developing an application where I need to make a connection to a server which is only accessible through a special APN. Therefore, I want to know, is it possible to specify an APN to use for a single connection (or application) only, and use that, possibly even if wifi is active?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your application will probably need the [WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_APN_SETTINGS) in order to be able to make APN changes. You can bring up a UI interface to have the user configure the APN with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Changing the settings programatically, on the other hand, is a bit more difficult. I recommend you take a look at the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903857/set-apn-programmatically-in-android) for more information.