# Send MMS from My application in android

Tags: java, android, mms, sendmessage

I want to send MMS from my application to a specific number. I've searched and found this code but I have no idea if this code what I need or not.
My Questions is :

-can anyone explain this code to me.i am beginner in MMS.

-also, i thought this code is let the user send MMS from my application without move it to the native Messaging inbox (and this is  what i want) Am i right?

-also i have a problem ,i do not know how can i put this code in my project.

this is what i found

MMS is just a http-post request. You should perform the request using extra network feature :

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final int result = connMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, Phone.FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS);
```

If you get back the result with `Phone.APN_REQUEST_STARTED` value, you have to wait for proper state. Register `BroadCastReciver` and wait until `Phone.APN_ALREADY_ACTIVE` appears:

```
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
context.registerReceiver(reciver, filter);
```

If background connection is ready, then build content and perform request. If you want to do that using android's internal code, please use this:

```
final SendReq sendRequest = new SendReq();
final EncodedStringValue[] sub = EncodedStringValue.extract(subject);
if (sub != null && sub.length > 0) {
   sendRequest.setSubject(sub[0]);
}
final EncodedStringValue[] phoneNumbers = EncodedStringValue.extract(recipient);
if (phoneNumbers != null && phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
   sendRequest.addTo(phoneNumbers[0]);
}

final PduBody pduBody = new PduBody();

if (parts != null) {
   for (MMSPart part : parts) {
      final PduPart partPdu = new PduPart();
      partPdu.setName(part.Name.getBytes());
      partPdu.setContentType(part.MimeType.getBytes());
      partPdu.setData(part.Data);
      pduBody.addPart(partPdu);
   }
}

sendRequest.setBody(pduBody);

final PduComposer composer = new PduComposer(this.context, sendRequest);
final byte[] bytesToSend = composer.make();

HttpUtils.httpConnection(context, 4444L, MMSCenterUrl, bytesToSendFromPDU, HttpUtils.HTTP_POST_METHOD, !TextUtils.isEmpty(MMSProxy), MMSProxy, port);
```

- MMSCenterUrl: url from MMS-APNs,
- MMSProxy: proxy from MMS-APNs,
- port: port from MMS-APNs

Note that some classes are from internal packages. Download from android git is required.
The request should be done with url from user's apn-space code:

```
public class APNHelper {

   public class APN {
      public String MMSCenterUrl = "";
      public String MMSPort = "";
      public String MMSProxy = ""; 
   }

   public APNHelper(final Context context) {
      this.context = context;
   }   

   public List<APN> getMMSApns() {     
      final Cursor apnCursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), null, null, null, null);
      if ( apnCursor == null ) {
         return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
      } else {
         final List<APN> results = new ArrayList<APN>();         
         while ( apnCursor.moveToNext() ) {
            final String type = apnCursor.getString(apnCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.TYPE));
            if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(type) && ( type.equalsIgnoreCase(Phone.APN_TYPE_ALL) || type.equalsIgnoreCase(Phone.APN_TYPE_MMS) ) ) {
               final String mmsc = apnCursor.getString(apnCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSC));
               final String mmsProxy = apnCursor.getString(apnCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPROXY));
               final String port = apnCursor.getString(apnCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPORT));                  
               final APN apn = new APN();
               apn.MMSCenterUrl = mmsc;
               apn.MMSProxy = mmsProxy;
               apn.MMSPort = port;
               results.add(apn);
            }
         }                   
         apnCursor.close();
         return results;
      }
```

**Please help me**

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Comment: Pleae refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20611335/2422453

Comment: Shouting no answer does not get an answer :/

Comment: Hello @Maha, have you got this solution to send MMS from our application. Actually, my application has a need to send an MMS with 2 images and some text. But how i didn't get the solution. Please help me if you can

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the android system functions:

Please have a look on

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
       intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
       if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
           startActivity(intent); }
}
```

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I found a link in an other thread to a github project that works 100% https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms

Notice, that obligatory settings are only

```
Settings sendSettings = new Settings();

sendSettings.setMmsc(mmsc);
sendSettings.setProxy(proxy);
sendSettings.setPort(port);
```

you can get them something like (found at [Set APN programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903857/set-apn-programmatically-in-android) - answear by vincent091):

```
Cursor cursor = null;
if (Utils.hasICS()){
    cursor =SqliteWrapper.query(activity, activity.getContentResolver(), 
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), APN_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
} else {
    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"),
        null, null, null, null);
}

cursor.moveToLast();
String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.TYPE));
String mmsc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSC));
String proxy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPROXY));
String port = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPORT));
```