# Android 4.0+ Error in Reading APN for sending an MMS

Tags: java, android

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10099 nor   current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.
```

What is the reason for getting this error when compiling the code of sending MMS? Why can't I read APNs in Android 4.0 and up?

Answer (score 1):

I am directly copied the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2) which is given by CommonsWare.

This appears to be an intentional change. The [git commit where they added this defense](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_telephonyprovider/commit/410a1228ec7aef66826f4aebf21cd26dc75ae82b) includes the following comment:

```
 Since the DB may contain corp passwords, we should secure it. Using the same permission as writing to the DB as the read is potentially as damaging as a write.
```

It is conceivable that your issue will cause them to consider adding a separate read permission, but at least for the time being, this is a regression in 4.2.

Comment: what do you mean by the regression? so with my current code, i can't read or write APN settings because it is not permitted? thanks for your answer

Comment: @michelle13  If you want to Read APN for Android 4.0+, there are changes to do. Follow the link I have given in the answer.