# Sending MMS programmatically in Android 4.2+

Tags: android

I've been trying to get the address, port, and proxy for sending an MMS programmatically. However, as of [Read APNs in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2), it seems that Google has removed the ability to query that information directly. I have found ways that work on some phones, but considering Google hasn't made it against policy to send MMS messages from third party apps, there has to be a good way to do it.

What's the current method for sending MMS in a post-4.2 Android world?