# Read APN settings (Not write)

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which will send MMS.
But to send mms in need to read APN settings of user.
I searched on internet. But the solution i get is by using Content Provider with uri of

***"content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"***.

But when ever i call it using

***Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn",null,null,null,null);***

It is throwing exception of "No permission to write APN settings".
But i only want to read. Not write.
Please tell me how to read apn settings. Only read, Not write.
I am developing application which will support SDK 15 and above.

Comment: You might have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18897139). I could only get it working by using reflection, however.

Comment: It is throwing security exception.

Comment: I guess there's really two different answers there. Which one did you try? I meant the one using the `android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper` class, under "And for Android 4.2 and more use this code :". I believe for lower versions, the first answer works, so it'll depend on which version your code is running under as to which method you should use.