# Android APN How to read and write it?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apn

I work on an app (> 4.4) and my boss would like to save the configuration of the APN into the SQLite (our database).

As this, if the APN is lost for a reason we can retrieve easily these information and configure it ..

Well, I've tried some code but actually NOTHING works ...

I get this error message:

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10081 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS.

Of course, I have added to the manifest the correct permission as this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APN_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

And here is it my code, it's with xamarin android but if you have some code with android , no matter i can find the translatation ..

```
Android.Net.Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://telephony/carriers");

// path to preferred APNs
Android.Net.Uri PREFERRED_APN_URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn");

//
Android.Database.ICursor cursor = ctx.ContentResolver.Query(PREFERRED_APN_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Thanks guys for all your time you spend here for to share your knowledge

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2

Comment: Hello guy, thanks for the links i've read the topic but nothing work every time i have the same problem about the permission ...I'm not sure but i think since version > 4 it's NOT ALLOW to create, update these information ...Could you confirm this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add these two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```