# Read APN from a device Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, apn

I've read a lot of topics about read APN by code with Android and it seems that it is not possible anymore since Android 4.2. However, all the topics are older than 2/3 years and I'd like to know if there is a good solution that enables me to read the current APN of a device. I've seen something about SQLiteWrapper but it does not work or maybe I'm just not enough qualified to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are right you cant read `APN Settings` from device onward from 4.1

> **Because**:
>   Since the DB may contain corp passwords, we should secure it. Using
>   the same permission as writing to the DB as the read is potentially as
>   damaging as a write. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453640/read-apns-in-android-4-2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to conclude that there si no solution about this ?