# Android send sms with subject

Tags: android, sms, subject

Hi I'm building an app which I'd like to programmatically send sms through which works fine however I can't figure out how to send a subject with the sms like all the sms apps out there can.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMS do not have subject lines.  I believe you would have to do MMS in order to have a subject line.  Here is a working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518393/send-mms-programmatically) on SO.  If you are referring to some of the 3rd part SMS system, they generally have everything in a raw string and then parse it to show you how they want, but there is not subject line in a SMS.

Comment: there's a column in content://sms/ called subject though? but I don't see that column in content://mms/

Comment: I think you're right though although i find what i wrote above odd?

Comment: I may be wrong, but you can send sms through email, and it is probably just a place holder for the data coming through as email to SMS.

Comment: When you add a subject line and/or picture, it becomes a MMS automatically since you are using the SmsMessage class for all three categories (SMS, MMS, EMAIL to Text).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Sms.SUBJECT column isn't used, at least by the native SMS app.  It may be a legacy column, intended to be populated from SMS-email gateways, but the comments in SmsMessageBase.extractEmailAddressFromMessageBody() make clear that this is no longer supported:

> ```
>  * Try to parse this message as an email gateway message
>  * There are two ways specified in TS 23.040 Section 3.8 :
>  *  - SMS message "may have its TP-PID set for Internet electronic mail - MT
>  * SMS format: [<from-address><space>]<message> - "Depending on the
>  * nature of the gateway, the destination/origination address is either
>  * derived from the content of the SMS TP-OA or TP-DA field, or the
>  * TP-OA/TP-DA field contains a generic gateway address and the to/from
>  * address is added at the beginning as shown above." (which is supported here)
>  * - Multiple addresses separated by commas, no spaces, Subject field delimited
>  * by '()' or '##' and '#' Section 9.2.3.24.11 (which are NOT supported here)
> ```

A given app can choose to populate the column itself, but the native app doesn't display its contents, and I'd bet that most others don't either.