# sending MMS in Android KitKat (API-19)

Tags: android

In my android application I want to send MMS from background service without user interaction, I tried to use `SmsManager.sendMultimediaMessage` but this method requires API-21 atleast and I am working on API-19 (Android KitKat). So please tell how can I send MMS from background service without user interaction in Android API level 19 (KitKat)?

Comment: Your users will hate you, and uninstall your app immediately. MMS have a cost. Which is much heavier than that of an SMS.

Comment: how can we send picture using SMS?

Comment: You **can't** share an image via SMS. But you can send it via eMail. Or share  the image on Telegram or Whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518393/send-mms-programmatically).

since i shouldn't answer with just a link. I copied some content from there.

```
Settings sendSettings = new Settings();

sendSettings.setMmsc(mmsc);
sendSettings.setProxy(proxy);
sendSettings.setPort(port);
```

you can get them something like (found at Set APN programmatically on Android - answear by vincent091):

```
Cursor cursor = null;
if (Utils.hasICS()){
    cursor =SqliteWrapper.query(activity, activity.getContentResolver(), 
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), APN_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
} else {
    cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"),
        null, null, null, null);
}

cursor.moveToLast();
String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.TYPE));
String mmsc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSC));
String proxy = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPROXY));
String port = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Carriers.MMSPORT));
```