# Message app doesn't show up when send MMS

Tags: java, android

My app is unable to open the Message app on my phone when I send an image via MMS:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto: "));  
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(ten));
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
{
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

But if I change this code to a sending SMS message code, the Message app will show up and allow users to send a message, but with MMS, it won't.

Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: you should probably look at the code of the application that doesn't open, rather than the code of the one that sends something

Comment: I've said that if I use the code for sending SMS, it will work, if I use the code for sending MMS, it won't work, that is the problem

Comment: well ... DUH. but it's the code RECEIVING the sent message that you should be looking at. For all we know it has a "message.type == sms -> open : ignore" configuration

Comment: you can see this answer it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611316/4961662